# Can't configure WebStorm Format code on save (JetBrains)

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to format the code when I use "Ctrl + S". Do not want to do "Ctrl + Alt + L" every time. I am using WebStorm 2020.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add your vote to the corresponding feature request: [IDEABKL-5806](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5806).

As a workaround, I'd suggest giving the [Save Actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) plugin a try

Comment: it is helped me